# Fastest way to index a new product i Solr with EE 1.14.0.1?

Tags: search, indexing, solr

I'm setting up a site on EE 1.14.0.1 with Solr search. Whats the fastest way to get a new product indexed in Solr (as in searchable in frontend)? I'm hoping there's a way without havng to reindexing everything.

Products are created through a custom integration if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, where $productInstance is a Magento instance of the product.

```
Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
    $productInstance, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
);
```

This is what happens when a product is saved and should queue up the product to be reindexed, just like saving the product in the admin system. Hopefully it will bypass the normal product save checks for if data has been changed.

It will need an active cron process running if you have indexes set to update on schedule and may take time to update on the front end.

The above is not tested thou.

Comment: What is ```self::ENTITY``` in this context?

Comment: Sorry, in this instance it should of been Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY. I have amended the original response.

Comment: For reference, the code is taken from the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::_afterSave() method.